# Shiny app is not working

Tags: r, shiny, typeerror, run-app

I try to build a shiny app with R but when I press RunApp the following Error Message appears:

**TypeError 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.b.')**

Any ideas to solve this problem? 
Shiny app looks like this:

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
              label = "Number of bins in histogram (approximate):",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50),
              selected = 20),

  checkboxInput(inputId = "individual_obs",
                label = strong("Show individual observations"),
                value = FALSE),

  checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
                label = strong("Show density estimate"),
                value = FALSE),

  plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "300px"),

  # Display this only if the density is shown
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
                   sliderInput(inputId = "bw_adjust",
                               label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                               min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
  )

))
```

**server.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({

    hist(faithful$eruptions,
         probability = TRUE,
         breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
         xlab = "Duration (minutes)",
         main = "Geyser eruption duration")

    if (input$individual_obs) {
      rug(faithful$eruptions)
    }

    if (input$density) {
      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions,
                      adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: Read [this thread on making a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5977215), then update your question with enough code for others to reproduce your question

Comment: Thanks. But the code is working on other laptops (Windows). I am using Rstudio on Mac.

Comment: I try to run 5 or 6 shiny apps which are already working on other laptops...

Comment: okay so for example the app above is not working. I also cannot find anything about this error message on google or other blogs..

Comment: your app is running fine on my system - Mac OS El Capitan running Rstudio  (1.0.44 )

Comment: I am using the same version 1.0.44. Did you change browser options on safari?

Comment: I used chrome - haven't tried safari

Comment: does the error appear in R (RStudio), or in the browser, as it looks like a javascript error

Comment: The error appears when I press RunApp in R. Do you have some more ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: I can only suggest to remove the UI elements one by one to try and find which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Please post the output from a `sessionInfo()` from the machine where you are getting the error. This will give us a better chance of a repro. It is probably something system or version dependent. It runs fine on my Windows 10 version 1607  machine with both R-Studio 0.99.903, R CRAN version 3.3.2, Shiny 0.14.2 and with RTVS 0.5, R Open 3.2.2, Shiny 0.12.2. A screen shot of the error would also help.

Comment: Thanks for all comments! I solved it - when I run the app using the console, the app works fine!